# Can't run distinct ADODB query on open workbook?

Tags: sql, vba, excel, adodb

I have a class `ADOConnector` for creating an ADODB connection to a workbook and querying the workbook:

```
Private objconnection As New ADODB.Connection

Sub connect(workbookPath As String)

 On Error GoTo errHandler
 objconnection.CommandTimeout = 99999999
 objconnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=" & workbookPath & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";"
 Exit Sub

 errHandler:
 Err.Raise Err.Number, "ADOConnector.connect", Err.Description & _
           " (" & workbookPath & ")"

End Sub

Function WorksheetQuery(selectSQL As String) As ADODB.Recordset

 Dim objrecordset As New ADODB.Recordset

 Const adOpenStatic = 3
 Const adLockOptimistic = 3
 Const adCmdText = &H1

 objrecordset.Open selectSQL, _
    objconnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

 If objrecordset.EOF Then
    Set WorksheetQuery = Nothing
    Exit Function
 End If

 Set WorksheetQuery = objrecordset

 Exit Function

 errHandler:
 Err.Raise Err.Number, "ADOConnector.WorksheetQuery", Err.Description
 Set WorksheetQuery = Nothing

End Function
```

I have a test method for `WorksheetQuery`:

```
Sub testADOcon()

Dim ac As New ADOConnector
Dim bkPath as string
bkPath = "U:\testFolder\testWorkbook.xlsx"
ac.connect bkPath
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = ac.WorksheetQuery("select distinct * from [report$]")

End Sub
```

This method gives strangely inconsistent results:

- If the workbook at `bkPath` is open, it fails with this error: `The connection for viewing your linked Microsoft Excel worksheet was lost.`
- If the workbook at `bkPath` is closed, it executes successfully.
- If `bkPath` is set as `bkPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName`, it executes successfully.
- If the SQL is changed to `"select * from [report$]"`, it executes successfully regardless of whether the workbook is open or closed.

How can I use `distinct` on another open workbook?

Comment: what if you use `distinctrow` instead of `distinct`?

Comment: @KazJaw, that works.  Any idea why?

Comment: @KazJaw, what if I want to select a certain column, e.g. `select distinct lastname from [report$]`?